# couchDB how to label Key and Value fields

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I am writing several CouchDB Views using the Fauxton interface.  What is the correct syntax to apply labels to the Key / Value output.  For example, instead of returning Key & Value to a User, I want to label the fields so the results are named "Created By" and "Created Time".

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your view result to a [list](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/transforming.html) to format your data.

Therefore, the appropriate way would be to add the labels locally.

Also, applications texts should be in the application, not in the database. For example, if you want to localize your labels, it would be easier if you had a dictionnary in your app and  you build labels from it.